# Using mui-pickers keyboardatepicker/keyboardatetimepickers, if giving direction:"rtl" then date format "dd/MMM/yyyy" giving wrong date format

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, muipickersutilsprovider

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gym2hf?file=/demo.js)

I need direction: I am using "rtl" for the Arabic language, but as I used dateformat "DD/MMM/YYYY" it is giving me output as MMM/DD/YYYY and also if you use `keyboarddatepickertime` with HH:mm then it is giving date in the format MMM/YYYY, HH:mm/DD. I also tried to raise this issue on mui/pickers github but they have made the repository view only. Please help.

This issue is also coming with the new mui-pickers versions. please help.